# Using Interface to convert objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have this entity class Map and I have created another partial class that implements the interface which basically carries common properties that is shared among classes.

```
namespace entity
{
    public partial class Map
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime date1 { get; set; } 

        public DateTime date2 { get; set; } 

        public int? test1 { get; set; }

        public int? test2 { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class Map : ICommonFields 
        {

        }

}

namespace Test
{
    public interface ICommonFields
    {
        Guid Id { get; set; }

        DateTime date1 { get; set; } 

        DateTime date2 { get; set; } 

    }
}
```

Now, in my code I get `List` of class `Map`

```
check(List<Map>);

private void check(List<ICommonFields> co)
{
   // do something
}
```

I get this error

> "cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list map to 
>   system.collections.generic.list ICommonfields"

How can I do this conversion, since I am only interested in common field `Id`, `date1` and `date2` ?

Comment: That's not a duplicate! Surely you need to use `Enumerable.Cast<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lack a bit of explaination but if I understand it right whhat you want to do is

```
var myList = new List<Map>();

/* loading of myList */

check(myList.ToList<ICommonFields>());
```